# How to ignore a folder in Zeitwerk for Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Simple question, but somehow the answer escapes me.

In moving to Rails 6 with Zeitwerk, I get:

```
Please, check the "Autoloading and Reloading Constants" guide for solutions.
 (called from <top (required)> at APP_ROOT/config/environment.rb:7)
rails aborted!
Zeitwerk::NameError: wrong constant name Enforce-calls-to-come-from-aws inferred by Module from directory

  APP_ROOT/app/junkyard/enforce-calls-to-come-from-aws

Possible ways to address this:

  * Tell Zeitwerk to ignore this particular directory.
  * Tell Zeitwerk to ignore one of its parent directories.
  * Rename the directory to comply with the naming conventions.
```

Which seems great: that's a junk folder and should never be loaded, so ignoring it makes perfect sense.

The Zeitwerk docs at https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk say

```
tests = "#{__dir__}/**/*_test.rb"
loader.ignore(tests)
loader.setup
```

is how you ignore a folder. Fair enough.  But how do I find `loader`?  The Rails guide on Zeitwerk autoloading (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) doesn't mention how to ignore folders directly, but does mention the autoloader stashed at `Rails.autoloaders.main`, so I figured that

```
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore("#{__dir__}/junkyard/**/*.rb")
```

or

```
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore("#{__dir__}/app/junkyard/**/*.rb")
```

would be the way to go.  No luck.  I've tried putting this in `application.rb` and in `initializers/zeitwerk.rb` and neither worked.

Any ideas where and how to ignore a folder with Zeitwerk within Rails?

PS: yes, I know I should just remove this from `app`, and I will.  But the question still vexes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I ran into this same issue, and it turns out it was complaining about a folder name.

Adding this to `application.rb` may work for you:

`Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join('app/junkyard'))`

Comment: Thanks @ajkerr, that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this! It worked for me to put this in an initializer which felt better than application.rb.

Comment: @IainBryson you should accept this answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 9):

I added this to `config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb`:

```
Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.ignore(Rails.root.join('app/ui'))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A lazy way of ignoring a directory, is to name with with a full-stop (period).

`.folder_to_be_ignored`

> Zeitwerk ignores automatically any file or directory whose name starts
> with a dot, and any files that do not have the extension ".rb". [Source](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk/blob/main/README.md#ignoring-parts-of-the-project)