# Elastic Beanstalk Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.2 platform update error: Early termination of worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Suddenly, after an automatic platform update to version 3.1.2, I get this message in the puma log repeatedly and constantly:

```
Early termination of worker
+ Gemfile in context: /var/app/current/Gemfile
```

But the log won't show what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, I fixed this error by adding this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'nio4r', '2.5.3'
```

and then running `bundle update`, pushing code and re-deploying my app.

I share a more detailed explanation into how I got to the solution in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352824/4482897)