# Puma "Early termination of worker" investigation difficult

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I've only updated my application's gems and moved to Rails `6.1.0.rc1` and am now unable to run `puma`. I see a number of messages that say `[7XXXX] Early termination of worker`.

I can replicate this locally by running `bundle exec puma -p 3000 -e production` but I do not see any other output in `log/production.log` or any of the other environments' logs.

At this point besides waiting for a new Rails rc I'm not sure how I can find the root of the issue. There is also no problem if I run `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -p 3000` or `bundle exec rails s`.

#### Additional Details

In `Gemfile`

```
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
```

and in `Gemfile.lock`

```
puma (4.3.6)
```

I updated to Puma `5.0.4` so I could use the `thread-backtraces` method on the [Control/Status Server](https://github.com/puma/puma#controlstatus-server) Puma can run. It was able to give me the following output which I'll dive into later but it didn't seem to provide a smoking gun.

```
[
    {
        "backtrace": [
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/cluster.rb:412:in `select'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/cluster.rb:412:in `run'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:171:in `run'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/puma:23:in `load'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'"
        ],
        "name": "Thread: TID-5ic"
    },
    {
        "backtrace": [
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/plugin/tmp_restart.rb:21:in `sleep'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/plugin/tmp_restart.rb:21:in `block in start'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/plugin.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in fire_background'"
        ],
        "name": "Thread: TID-5iw puma plugin background 0"
    },
    {
        "backtrace": [
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/reactor.rb:70:in `select'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/reactor.rb:70:in `select_loop'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/reactor.rb:34:in `block in run'"
        ],
        "name": "Thread: TID-5jg puma reactor"
    },
    {
        "backtrace": [
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:308:in `sleep'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:308:in `block in start!'"
        ],
        "name": "Thread: TID-5k0 puma threadpool reaper"
    },
    {
        "backtrace": [
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:308:in `sleep'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:308:in `block in start!'"
        ],
        "name": "Thread: TID-5kk puma threadpool trimmer"
    },
    {
        "backtrace": [
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/server.rb:323:in `select'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/server.rb:323:in `handle_servers'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/server.rb:258:in `block in run'"
        ],
        "name": "Thread: TID-5l4 puma server"
    },
    {
        "backtrace": [
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:219:in `backtrace'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:219:in `block in thread_status'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:215:in `each'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:215:in `thread_status'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/app/status.rb:59:in `call'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/server.rb:430:in `process_client'",
            "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/puma-5.0.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'"
        ],
        "name": "Thread: TID-5og puma threadpool 001"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please add some logs? Also please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/62079968 . it might help you

Comment: Thanks @Vishal. I read that post before posting myself but I'm having the problem locally. I'll update my post to include the versioning info as well. The primary problem is that I cannot find any logs to read through or post for better minds than mine! There's nothing added to `log/production.log` and the only STDOUT is the early termination message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Unexpected!

`pumactl` and having a `control-url` helped but a friend of mine suggested the best idea that I only wish was more obvious,

> are you throwing the error on a different server?

I ran `gem install thin` and `RAILS_ENV=production thin start` finally showed me the error I was looking for!

As it turns out, I should not have been using non-public methods like `add_template_helper` as `ActionMailer::Base` may not always get all the methods of `ActionController::Base`. I didn't see this error in development because Rails does not eagerly load all of your classes.

Comment: great.. !! Maybe this answer will help many people in the future.

Comment: I hope it will. If I scrape together the time I'd like to find out why I could not get this information easily from puma. However, my friend's epiphany of using another server is the major takeaway as that will come in handy again later I'm sure.

Comment: Indeed, a friend always take out us from problem :)

Comment: Wow nice one! Thin did print the full stack and error! <3