# Rails 6 + Zeitwerk, loading files without class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, zeitwerk

We are upgrading to Rails 6, and have done most of the work to make our application work with Zeitwerk.

We do have two files, which are query objects, existing under `app/queries` and we don't define a class for them. They exists with methods only.

However, Zeitwerk expects the file to define a constant, but we don't deem it necessary.

Is there any way to tell Zeitwerk that we want to load these files as is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore a folder in Zeitwerk for Rails 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125879/how-to-ignore-a-folder-in-zeitwerk-for-rails-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell the main autoloader to ignore them:

```rb
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(
  Rails.root.join("app/queries/foo.rb"),
  Rails.root.join("app/queries/bar.rb")
)
```

And then the application is responsible for loading them using `require` or whatever.

If everything under `app/queries` should be ignored, you can ignore the directory itself:

```rb
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join("app/queries"))
```

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you! Really helpful.