Routes.rb doesnt define constant Routes
I am a SysAdmin working Redmine. We are upgrading our system and trying to get the older pluging Redmine_out_of_band_authentication to get an email with with a verification code working.
Before someone says it, yes I know MFA is built into the system now and it works quite handily... as long as you can work in environments where cameras and phones are allowed. This is system is use in a secure environment. I have this to the point where I get the following error:
expected file plugins/redmine_out_of_band_auth/app/config/routes.rb to define constant Routes

The file in question contains:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :out_of_band_auth do
    resources :out_of_band_auths_controller do
      get :login
      post :login
    end
  end
end


I am assuming it was written before Zeitwerk. Can anyone point out any syntax errors? I have spent WAAY too much time fighting this and I am not a Ruby/Rails developer.
Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated! Also, please dont assume I know what file you just allude to. Please spell it out for me.
I was expecting it to install like all the other plugins and not waste over two weeks fighting it!

Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125879/how-to-ignore-a-folder-in-zeitwerk-for-rails-6

Unfortunately, no change. I was hoping someone would say it was just formatted wrong. But alas.

config directory should be outside of the app directory: plugins/redmine_out_of_band_auth/config/* https://github.com/matsukei/redmine_out_of_band_auth

You haven't specified what Ruby and Rails versions you are using.
Also, you are using an open-source plugin that appears to have been unmaintained for over 7 years. As opposed to trying to get an abandoned piece of software working, have you considered exploring well-supported alternatives that can accomplish the same end goals?

engineersmnky - Went back and made sure it was exactly as you said, no change.  Alex, zeitwerks kicks up unless they are under apps.  and Matthew, if there was a better option..I woudl use it. There no other plugins that do this that I can find. If I try to install software it has to be on an approved list, the plugins are just scripts so that doesnt apply.

you're not supposed to autoload the whole config directory, as you can see from the error you're getting. routes are loaded during application boot, zeitwerk isn't used for that.

@user27552065 is this some sort of policy at your workplace? It sounds absolutely ridiculous to split into scripts and software along some arbitrary line like that.

I am not familiar with these plugins, but probably you have to configure the autoloader to ignore app/config (see ignore in Zeitwerk's docs).
